# Show that if $G$ and $H$ are groups then $Z(G \times H) = Z(G) \times Z(H)$

Tags: group-theory

Show that if $G$ and $H$ are groups then $Z(G \times H) = Z(G) \times Z(H)$.

I'm not too sure how to begin, I know I can find some element from $Z(G \times H)$ that is also in $Z(G) \times Z(H)$ and vice versa but I don't know how to set up the initial procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(g,h) \in G \times H$. If $(g,h) \in Z(G \times H)$, then $(g,h)(x,y) = (x,y)(g,h)$ for every $(x,y) \in G \times H$. We have that
$$(g,h)(x,y) = (gx,hy) = (xg,yh) = (x,y)(g,h).$$
Use it to show that $Z(G \times H) \subset Z(G) \times Z(H)$. The converse can be solved in a similar way.